# C++ Ordering the names of a scoreboard

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to arrange the scores on a scoreboard. I'm reading the scores from one file and the names attached to scores from another and putting each of them into their own vector.

For this test I'm limiting the number of entries to 5, so the code below adds a new one as a test, after which the scores vector gets sorted and the 6th entry gets deleted.

The problem I'm having is sorting the list of names once I've added a new score, obviously I need the names to stay assigned to their scores. This is my main function so far

```
vector<int> scoreboard_scores(5);
scoreboard_scores[0]=10;
scoreboard_scores[1]=9;
scoreboard_scores[2]=8;
scoreboard_scores[3]=7;
scoreboard_scores[4]=6;

vector<string> scoreboard_names(5);
scoreboard_names[0]="a";
scoreboard_names[1]="b";
scoreboard_names[2]="c";
scoreboard_names[3]="d";
scoreboard_names[4]="e";

// Adding new score/name for testing
int newscore;
cout << "Enter new score: ";
cin >> newscore;

string newname;
cout << "Enter new name: ";
cin >> newname;

scoreboard_scores.push_back(newscore);
scoreboard_names.push_back(newname);
//-------------------------

// Sorting the scores vector
sort(scoreboard_scores.begin(),scoreboard_scores.end());
reverse(scoreboard_scores.begin(),scoreboard_scores.end());
scoreboard.pop_back();
```

Now I'm confused at how to arrange the names in the same way. I've looked up a couple different methods but they're way beyond my understanding of C++, I have a very shallow understanding of classes and the solution to this seems to rely on them.

Thanks :)

Comment: Try using a vector of structs instead of two vectors, so the vector items contain both the name and the score.

Comment: Or vector of `std::pair`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a vector of pairs:

```
vector<pair<int, string> > scoreboard(5);
```

assign values like that:

```
scoreboard[0] = make_pair(10, "a");
scoreboard[1] = make_pair(9, "b");
scoreboard[2] = make_pair(8, "c");
scoreboard[3] = make_pair(7, "d");
scoreboard[4] = make_pair(6, "e");
```

Define a function that will compare pairs (before main)

```
bool comparePair(const pair<int, string>& first, const pair<int, string>& second)
{
    return first.first > second.first;
}
```

What it does is take two arguments of type pair and compare their first elements. Using `>` allows to have descending order.

After inserting new element sort with:

```
sort(scoreboard.begin(), scoreboard.end(), comparePair);
```

EDIT: The sort will use `comparePair` function to compare elements in your vector. By modifying it you can change the order of elements. And if you ever want to sort by the name not value, you simply change the return to: `return first.second > second.second;`

Comment: Thanks! It works great :) Not really sure how the comparePair function works though. Does it return 1 if first.first > second.first, and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. `first.first` is the way to access the number in first pair (`first.second` accesses the string). And it does exactly that, but it returns `true` or `false` not 1 and 0

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you probably want a `std::map`.

If your `scoreboard_names` are immutable and unique then you could just do this to construct your `scoreboard`:

```
map<string, int> scoreboard{{"a", 10}, {"b", 9}, {"c", 8}, {"d", 7}, {"e", 6}};
```

Adding to your `scoreboard` could be done like this:

```
scoreboard.insert(make_pair(newname, newscore));
```

And in `std::map` everything is sorted by key, here being your `std::string`.
To iterate in reverse just use `rbegin` and `rend` instead of `begin` and `end`.

Your code could be rewritten like this:

```
map<string, int> scoreboard{ { "c", 8 }, { "a", 10 }, { "b", 9 }, { "d", 7 }, { "e", 6 } };

// Adding new score/name for testing
int newscore;
cout << "Enter new score: ";
cin >> newscore;

string newname;
cout << "Enter new name: ";
cin >> newname;

for_each(scoreboard.begin(), scoreboard.end(), [](pair<string, int> i){cout << '(' << i.first << ", " << i.second << ")\n"; });
for_each(scoreboard.rbegin(), scoreboard.rend(), [](pair<string, int> i){cout << '(' << i.first << ", " << i.second << ")\n"; });

scoreboard.erase(prev(scoreboard.end()));

for_each(scoreboard.begin(), scoreboard.end(), [](pair<string, int> i){cout << '(' << i.first << ", " << i.second << ")\n"; });
```

Comment: You can provide map with comparator. Also the score should be the key, so `map<int, string, std::greater<int> > scoreboard` will be perfect and in the desired order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Based on your first comment about scoreboard_names, I don't think this will work because I want to allow the names for different scores to be the same

Comment: @HarryKeen I think that a map would still be the way that you want to go, but I'd recommend a [`std::multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/) in that case.